# View takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, openai-api

Trying to make a POST request to openAI with the input:

```
{"write hello world"}
```

but getting the error:

```
TypeError: View.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my view:

```
def get_help(user_input):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt="user_input",
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1024,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0
    )
    return response["choices"][0]["text"]

@api_view(['POST'])
class receive_response(View):
    def post(self, request):
        user_input = request.POST["user_input"]
        response = get_help(user_input)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

and my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("get", get_help, name="get_help"),
    path("post", receive_response, name="post"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line: `class receive_response(View):`

(Why does `receive_response` inherit from view?)

Essentially what is happening is:

- `POST` Request is received
- `request_received` object is initialized (with the args of the `POST` - of which there must be two)
- since it inherits from `View` (and no `__init__()` is specified, the parent class' `__init__()` is passed the same inputs
- since `View.__init__()` accepts a single input value, but it received two, you get your error: `TypeError: View.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Add a `def __init__(self, v1, v2):` declaration to your class, and debug it to see what v1/v2 are (and decide which/what to pass to `super().__init__()` (View's constructor)